# ASP.NET MVC ActionResult How to return data in response to GET request

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm having trouble creating a method in response to AJAX GET request from the Javacript. I have debugged it and it goes into the GET response method in the back-end and retrieves the proper data, but I am not sure how to return the data to the front.

Here is my code :
Backend:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetOldEntries()
    {
        var data = db.Entries.Where(e => e.Date.Month != DateTime.Now.Month);
        return data; // How do I properly return data?
    }
```

Front End:

```
$.get('/Home/GetOldEntries', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetOldEntries()
    {
        var data = db.Entries.Where(e => e.Date.Month != DateTime.Now.Month);
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```

Try the above

Comment: Thanks that worked. But I ended up getting a circle reference error. I added this line to make it all work:
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;